# Ambiguous function call with two parameter packs

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

The following compiles in clang but not in gcc:

```
template <class... Ts, class... Args>
void f(Ts&&..., Args&&...);

int main()
{
    f();
}
```

This is the error I get in GCC:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:30:7: error: no matching function for call to 'f()'
     f();
       ^
main.cpp:30:7: note: candidate is:
main.cpp:23:6: note: template<class ... Ts, class ... Args> void f(Ts&& ..., Args&& ...)
 void f(Ts&&..., Args&&...)
      ^
main.cpp:23:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:30:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
     f();
       ^
```

If I give an argument like `f(0)` then it compiles with GCC but not with Clang.

Error with clang:

```
main.cpp:30:5: error: no matching function for call to 'f'
    f(0);
    ^
main.cpp:23:6: note: candidate function not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
void f(Ts&&..., Args&&...)
     ^
1 error generated.
```

If I give the same number of explicit template arguments as function parameters then it compiles with both compilers (i.e `f<int, int, int>(0, 0, 0)`).

Comment: I don't see how this is supposed to work. If you call `f(1, 2, 3, 4)` or even `f<int, int, int, int>(1, 2, 3, 4)` - which are `Ts` and which are `Args`? How can the compiler tell where the former end and the latter begin? Is it two and two, one and three, zero and four?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I didn't expect any of them to work.

Comment: Submit a bug-report "accepts-invalid" to each.

Comment: It seems you can even add more parameter packs and get the same behaviour...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second template parameter pack `Args` is indeed deduced:

> A trailing template parameter pack (14.5.3) not otherwise deduced will
>   be deduced to an empty sequence of template arguments.

Taking that into account it also becomes clear that e.g. `f<int>(0)` is well-formed. However, `Ts` is never deduced. [temp.deduct.call]/1:

> When a function parameter pack appears in a non-deduced context
>   (14.8.2.5), **the type of that parameter pack is never deduced**.

Note that the previous quote doesn't apply to `Ts`, as it isn't trailing. Therefore, pure deduction will always fail.